# Is it possible to have recommended apps for corporate phones?

Tags: store

We have a lot of Windows Phone devices as our corporate company mobiles - is there any way to set them up so that we can have our own "recommended apps" type of section in the market place (much like a carrier's or OEM's section?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get hub integration like the carriers do. What is recommended is to have an app that incorporates this functionality. You can even include built in corporate purchasing, so the employee does not have to pay for it, and so the company can control who gets which apps.